# Getopts considers my option chain as the argument for the first one

Tags: bash, shell, parsing, arguments, getopts

The following code is executed in `subscript.sh`, and `subscript.sh` is run inside `primaryscript.sh`

```
#### primaryscript.sh
#! /bin/bash
#...
"$bss_path"/subscript.sh "$option"
#...
```

I am using this code to parse my arguments and their values:

```
#### subscript.sh
#! /bin/bash

while getopts "hw:l:s:b:" opt; do
  case $opt in
    w)
      x="$OPTARG";;
    l)
      xx="$OPTARG";;
    s)
      xxx="$OPTARG";;
    b)
      xxxx="$OPTARG";;
    h)
      print_usage
      exit 0;;  
    \?)
      echo "Invalid option: -$OPTARG"
      exit 1;;
  esac
done
```

The problem appears when I call my script with multiple arguments:

```
./myscript -l 5.0.3-0 -s 4.0-0 -b 010
```

`getopts` thinks that option `l` have `5.0.3-0 -s 4.0-0 -b 010` as argument.

What am I doing wrong?

I tried to play around with the `:` and the option, but as I understood I have to put them behind the options taking an argument right?

And `getopts` naturally knows that `-` is the separator for arguments.

```
$> echo $BASH_VERSION
$> 3.2.25(1)-release
```

Comment: With bash 3.1.17 (from RHEL 5) and 4.2.8 (from Ubuntu 11.04): If I add this as last line it works fine for me: `echo -e "w: $x\nl: $xx\ns: $xxx\nb: $xxxx"`

Comment: Add line which executes this scipt and show shebang of this script. Btw. your script works fine with bash, sh, dash and zsh.

Comment: Remove quotes: `"$option"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Cyrus pointed out in the comment, the problem was how I passed arguments.

```
./myscript "$options"
```

The correct way is :

```
./myscript $options
```

Since "$options" won't care of the spaces and take the whole string as a single argument.

Comment: What is `$options` and where does it come from? The correct way to pass options from one script to another one is to use `"$@"`; if you need to keep them in an intermediate variable, use an array rather than a simple variable (assuming you are using bash or some other shell which has arrays.)

Comment: I generate the options of my script using complex logic beforehand, and creating an 'option string' cotaining multiple options. I think I am not wrong, my mistake was to put them as a single argument instead of multiple ones

Answer (score 0):

It works for me.  You can read more about GETOPTS, OPTARG as well as the while loop and case statement by typing "man bash" in your shell and searching.

```
#!/bin/bash

while getopts "hw:l:s:b:" opt; do
  case $opt in
    w)
      x="$OPTARG";;
    l)
      xx="$OPTARG";;
    s)
      xxx="$OPTARG";;
    b)
      xxxx="$OPTARG";;
    h)
      print_usage
      exit 0;;
    \?)
      echo "Invalid option: -$OPTARG"
      exit 1;;
  esac
done

echo $xx
echo $xxxx
echo $xxx
```

Output:

```
5.0.3-0
010
4.0-0
```

Comment: Hum actually it works for me too if I just use this piece of code... I am confused. I edited my question

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, including an explanation of *how* and *why* this solves the problem [would really help](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Adding [an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/40761779/revisions) telling people to `man bash` really isn't an explanation of *how* and *why* this solves the problem.